# Is my program Turing-complete?

Tags: haskell, turing-complete

I spent a week or two programming a simple logic solver. Having built it, I found myself wondering whether the language it solves is Turing-complete or not. So I coded up a small set of equations which accept any valid expression in the SKI combinator calculus, and produce a result set which contains the normal form of that expression. Since SKI *is* Turing-complete, proving that my language can execute SKI would demonstrate its Turing-completeness.

There is a glitch, however. The solver does not reduce the expression in normal order. Actually what it does is to try *every possible reduction order*. Which means that the solution set is typically *huge*. If a normal form exists, it will be in there *somewhere*, but it's difficult to tell *where*.

This brings me to two questions:

- Is my language Turing-complete? Or do I need to find a better proof?
- Is the number of solutions a computable function of the input?

(At first I assumed that the size of the solution set was exponential or factorial in the input size. But on closer inspection, this is not true. You can write huge expressions which are already in normal form, and tiny expressions which do not terminate. I have a feeling that determining the size of the solution set might be equivilent to solving the Halting Problem, but I'm not completely sure...)

Comment: What happens if one reduction order does not terminate while another one does?  Do you get the terminating one?

Comment: Oh, and your SKI implementation is all the proof I need that it's Turing complete.

Comment: @augustss I have carefully arranged that the code tries normal order reduction _first_. So if a normal form exists, it will be at a finite position in the solution set. However, if a non-terminating reduction order exists, the soler is guaranteed to find it, and produce an infinite solution set. Is producing an infinite set which _contains_ the right answer _somewhere_ sufficient for Turing-completeness? I mean, simply enumerating all possible SKI expressions would do that...

Comment: First, I assume your solution set is ordered in some fashion when it's presented.  (Otherwise you'd not see anything interesting.)  If so, why isn't the normal order reduction the first one to appear?

Comment: Solutions are numbered in the order that the solver discovers them. The entire reduction sequence appears, not just the end result. Without knowing how long the reduction sequence is, it's not possible to tell where the irreducible result will appear.

Comment: In your formulation, if you write a tiny expression which does not terminate, does that mean that it has an empty solution set or an infinite solution set?

Comment: @sclv Each step in the reduction sequence is a solution. So if any infinite reduction sequences exist, the solution set is infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A) As augustss says, your system is clearly turing complete.

B) You're right that determining solution size is the same as the halting problem. If a sequence doesn't terminate, then you get an infinite solution set. So to determine if the set is infinite, you need to determine if a reduction sequence terminates. But that's *precisely* the halting problem!

C) As I recall, a system that, given a set of instructions to a turing machine, merely says how many steps they take to terminate (which is, I suppose, the cardinality of your solution set) or fails to terminate if the instructions themselves fail to terminate is *in itself* turing complete. So that should help with the intuition here.

Comment: Nice answer, but one thing still worries me: It is possible for an expression to possess a normal form, and yet a reduction order still exists which does not terminate. In this case, the solution set is still infinite, even though the normal order reduction does terminate. So the cardinality of the solution set is not _precisely_ the same as whether the reduction terminates or not... I'm not sure whether or not this invalidates your argument.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to my own question... I found that by tweaking the source code, I can make it so that if the input SKI expression has a normal form, that normal form will always be solution #1. So if you just ignore any further solutions, the program reduces any SKI expression to normal form.

I believe this constitutes a "better proof". ;-)